# How to pass an array of migration instances in umzug config

Tags: webpack, sequelize.js, umzug, electron-vue

I'm using umzug to run the migrations in my electron-vue app, because of the webpack I can't use the path like

```
migrations: {
    path: __dirname + '/../migrations',
    pattern: /\.js$/
}
```

So I heard I can pass migrations instances, but I don't know how I do that.

So far I have this:

```
// sequelize initialization, etc...

let migrations = [
    require('../migrations/20180427160552-create-user'),
    require('../migrations/20180515205633-create-visits'),
    require('../migrations/20180515205633-create-vehicles')
];

var Umzug = require('umzug');
var umzug = new Umzug({
    storage: 'sequelize',
    storageOptions: {
    sequelize: sequelize
    },
    migrations: migrations
});
umzug.up().then(function (migrations) { });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use customResolver

```
async function checkMigrations() {
  const umzug = new Umzug({
    storage: 'sequelize',
    storageOptions: {
      sequelize,
    },
    migrations: {
      params: [
        sequelize.getQueryInterface(),
        Sequelize,
        function() {
          throw new Error('Migration tried to use old style "done" callback.');
        }
      ],
      path: 'path/to/migrations',
      pattern: /\.js$/,
      customResolver: function(migrationFile) {
        return require(`./migrations/${path.basename(migrationFile, '.js')}`);
      }
    },
    logging: function() {
      console.log.apply(null, arguments);
    },
  });

  return umzug.up();
}
```

The point is to use "prefix" folder as literal, but not as variable.
This will not work:

```
customResolver: function(migrationFile) {
    return require(`${some-path}/${some-file}`);
}
```

But this will:

```
customResolver: function(migrationFile) {
    return require(`/absolute-or-relative-prefix-folder/${filename-based-on-func-argument}`);
}
```

Comment: how do I pass the value of 'migrationFile' as the function argument ?

Comment: What do you mean? As usual: `let filename_based_on_func_argument = extract_filename_func(migrationFile)`